# How can I expand the short URL "4sq.com/xCMa****" to full length real URL "foursquare.com/someone/checkin/4f5d****"

Tags: twitter, foursquare

I'm currently working on a research project that needs to collect checkin tweets from Twitter.

A crawler has been implemented and tweets I got are in the format like: "I'm at SOMEWHERE 4sq.com/xW1q**"

When click on the link "4sq.com/xW1q**", the page will be redirect to URL like "foursquare.com/SOMEONE/checkin/**CHECKINID**&**SIGNATURE**". I need to extract the CHECKINID and SIGNATURE in order to get detailed checkin infomation.

What I want to ask is that how can I program to **expand** the shorter URL to the longer URL in order to obtain the checkin ID and a signature ? Someone suggest that I should make a **HEAD request** to get the the full URL, but I don't know how to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New more correct answer**

4sq.com uses bit.ly to shorten URLs, so you should use the bit.ly API to expand the URL: http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation

<strike>A `HEAD` request is the right thing to do.</strike>

To do a `HEAD` request in curl:

```
curl -i -X HEAD http://4sq.com/abcdefg
```

Which returns the headers like so:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2012 14:26:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
...other headers...
Location: <<<FULL URL>>>
```

If you tell us more about what language you're coding in we can give you more specific advice about how to make a HEAD request and get that header value.

Comment: Thanks! I resolved this problem by myself. I used "HttpURLConnection" in Java and it worked. Anyway, appreicate for your correct answer.

Comment: BTW. Hall, After I extract CHECKINID and SIGNATURE from the full URL, the next step is to get the latitude and longtitude value of the place where the checkin happens. Any hits about how to do it?

Comment: Please see updated answer, there is a better way than HEAD requests.